# SwiftUI: making forever animation of y offset in a filled horizontal image

Tags: ios, swift, image, animation, swiftui

I'm trying to animate an image inside a "row" by it's y axis so that it appears that you would the view would slowly scroll vertically through the entire image. And when done, it backtracks. I hope that makes sense. I'm trying to do it in this code:

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack {
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    WebImage(url: self.url)
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .resizable()
                        .placeholder {
                            ImageStore.shared.image(name: "exploras-icon")
                        }
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .animate {
                          // animate by y offset within bounds of HStack
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 140)
            .clipped()
        }
    }
```

Any help/guidance much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

[image: demo]

```
struct TestAutoScrollImage: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { gp in
            HStack {
                Image("large_image")
            }
            .frame(width: gp.size.width, height: gp.size.height, alignment: self.isActive ? .bottom : .top)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea([.top, .bottom])
        .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 5).repeatForever())
        .onAppear {
            self.isActive = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the input! I have not managed to get it to work using the stacks tat I had in the original question though.